Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a| \leq b$ then $-b \leq a \leq b$.
Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a| \leq b$ then $-b \leq a \leq b$.
Solving by cases.
Case 1: $a$ $\ge$  0. $|a| \leq b$ follows $a\le b$. Since $a$ $\ge$  0, it can be concluded that $0$ $\leq$$a \leq b$ and hence,  $-b \leq a \leq b$.
Case 2: $a$ $\lt$  0.  $|a| \leq b$ follows $-a$ $\le$ $b$=$a$ $\ge$$-b$. Since  $a$ $\lt$  0, it follows that $0$ $\gt$ $a$ $\ge$ $-b$, and hence  $-b \leq a \leq b$.
For the last part in both cases, am i right to assume that given ,$a$ is less/more than or equal to $0$ , that i can derive my conclusion? Or is there a flaw in my logic here. Thanks

You are right yes.

You are right. But you should write $-a\leq b\iff a\geq -b$ (write an $\iff$ instead of an $=$).

Your proof is not complete. For instance in the first case, you should justify $-b\le a$.

@AnneBauval Any hints? For the first case, my thought process was since $a$ $\ge$ $0$, then essentially $-b$ $\le$ $a$

Justify why $-b\le0$, even if it seems "obvious" to all of us. Otherwise one could argue that the statement itself to be proven is obvious.

@AnneBauval To be truly rigorous, one has to begin with a rigorous definition of $\le$ (and $\ge$), actually. If you don’t do that, you can just say it’s obvious.

We don't need to define $\le$: we just take any linearly ordered group. @Darren: what I meant was: if $0\le a\le b$ then $b\ge0$ hence $-b\le0$.
